# WebMvcTest: Migrating from WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to SecurityFilterChain

Tags: spring-security, spring-test-mvc

As described [here](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter) Spring Security deprecated `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` which I've been using for some time. I used the component based approach and introduced `SecurityFilterChain` and `InMemoryUserDetailsManager` beans (see: [commit](https://github.com/pszemus/spring-security-test/commit/fb9b40194747a3b45678183276b81c582cb004a3)) but then one of my tests, which is using `@WithMockUser` failed.

Does `@WebMvcTest` tests work with `@WithMockUser` when using Spring Security component based approach (`SecurityFilterChain`)?

- Tests: https://github.com/pszemus/spring-security-test/blob/master/src/test/java/com/example/springsecuritytest/TestControllerTest.java
- Old security configuration that used `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` (for which all tests pass): https://github.com/pszemus/spring-security-test/blob/c323ce3af77bb067c7eef58fd933689ef97c082c/src/main/java/com/example/springsecuritytest/SecurityConfiguration.java
- New security configuration that use component-based approach (`givenMockedCredentials_shouldAccessSecuredEndpoint` test fails with message: [Status expected:<200> but was:<401>](https://github.com/pszemus/spring-security-test/blob/fb9b40194747a3b45678183276b81c582cb004a3/tests-result.txt)): https://github.com/pszemus/spring-security-test/blob/fb9b40194747a3b45678183276b81c582cb004a3/src/main/java/com/example/springsecuritytest/SecurityConfiguration.java

Whole project, with failing test, is located: https://github.com/pszemus/spring-security-test

Comment: `I used the component based approach and introduced SecurityFilterChain and InMemoryUserDetailsManager` and where is that code, and where is you security debug logs that will tell you the reason for the 401?

Comment: Try adding `@Import(YourSecurityConfiguration.class)` in your test class

Comment: @MarcusHertdaCoregio that was it! Thank you so much! If you post your advice as an answer, I'll make it an accepted one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add `@Import(YourSecurityConfiguration.class)` in your test class. The `@WebMvcTest` is not picking up the configuration automatically, so you have to tell it explicitly which configuration to use.

Comment: I had the same problem, it would be nice include this information in the official link: https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter

Comment: This information is present in the testing section of Spring Boot https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.testing.slice-tests

Comment: Considering above link explains how to migrate Spring Security to work without WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, makes sense to include how to adapt your tests too. Allowing to the people with a similar problem find the "whole solution" in only one location