# How to make user login and register uwing Spring Security with JWT?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

In a Spring Boot app, I am trying to implement a user login, signup and JWT feature using Spring Security. I will also use MySQL and save the user to the database.

I have searched and found many examples, but most of them uses different approaches and I am really too confused about the most proper one or is there a better up-to date approach.

Here are some examples that seems the most proper, but really not sure. So, could you please have a look at them or give me some suggestion with a proper article or example?

https://www.bezkoder.com/spring-boot-security-login-jwt/

https://www.bezkoder.com/spring-boot-jwt-mysql-spring-security-architecture/

https://blog.iamprafful.com/spring-boot-rest-api-authentication-best-practices-using-jwt-2022#comments-list

https://dev.to/nilmadhabmondal/let-s-implement-jwt-based-authentication-in-spring-boot-5e10

**Update:** On the other hand, as `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is deprecated, I think I should use an approach without `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. But all of the 10-15 solutions are using `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. For details I also look at [Spring Security without the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter).

So, any example that is not using deprecated `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`?

Comment: This link will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72801939/webmvctest-migrating-from-websecurityconfigureradapter-to-securityfilterchain, not only about how to migrate from a previous `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` configuration (https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter), but even what you need to do in your Junits if you are using `@WebMvcTest`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I read the blog and will read other page that seems also very useful

Comment: I just upgraded a personal project and you can see an example about it with the current version: https://github.com/doctore/Spring5Microservices/blob/master/order-service/src/main/java/com/order/configuration/security/WebSecurityConfiguration.java and the previous one using `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`: https://github.com/doctore/Spring5Microservices/blob/archive/v0/master/order-service/src/main/java/com/order/configuration/security/WebSecurityConfiguration.java

Comment: However, it's important to know that I'm using this project for learning purposes, that is, there are parts that could be used in a "real" application and others that are not recommended. As @DucVo says, learn about security and Spring using official documentation is always a sure bet, allowing you distinguish which websites contain suitables examples to use.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion before working with Spring Security, you should be know about Architecture of Spring Security and Spring Security Authentication:

The offical document at:

- [Spring Security Servlet architecture](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/architecture.html)
- [Spring Security Authentication architecture](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/architecture.html)

About the link you provide, I think this is the best for know architecture:

- https://www.bezkoder.com/spring-boot-jwt-mysql-spring-security-architecture/

And don't hesitance about up to date, just do it and you will find the best way.Hope you enjoy the Spring Security.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these good explanations, voted up. On the other hand,  **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is deprecated from Spring 2.7.0**. So, any example that is not using deprecated `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`?

Comment: The links she has provided are all bad practices, since they all write custom security solution which in turn is bad practice. You saying that one of the links is ”best” is not true, that link is bad.

Comment: @Toerktumlare yes it not a best practice but I think it's good enough to learn about 
 the basis architecture of security.

Comment: @Rosa I see the link you give have a sample for this https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter. Many way you can implement but when you have knowledge about Architecture Spring Security, you can replace old version with new version. So long as, you know how it work.

Comment: Actually I read that but my problem is finding a proper example. Yes, I also updated the deprecated code, thanks a lot for your helps.

Comment: @DucVo On the other hand, I am struggling with exception handling (I cannot make them work with ControllerAdvice. Any idea on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74337289/controlleradvice-catch-authenticationexception-before-spring-security