# ControllerAdvice catch AuthenticationException before Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, spring-security

I am using `ControllerAdvice` for handling exceptions in my app and it is working properly. However, I started to use Spring Security and normally I should catch the AuthenticationExceptions in the following method.

```
@Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
        AuthenticationException authException)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.error("Unauthorized error: {}", authException.getMessage());

        response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);

        final Map<String, Object> body = new HashMap<>();
        body.put("status", HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        body.put("error", "Unauthorized");
        body.put("message", authException.getMessage());
        body.put("path", request.getServletPath());

        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), body);
    }
```

When I remove my exception handling classses, I can catch AuthenticationException in this method. **BUT**, when I use my exception handling mechanishm, it catche the AuthenticationExceptions before this `commence` method.

I tried to use `@Order(value = Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)`, but it does not make any sens. So, how can I catch AuthenticationException in this `commence` method by preventing ControllerAdvice catched them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So try to add annotation  `@ExceptionHandler(AuthenticationException.class)`:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerExceptionHandler {

@ExceptionHandler(AuthenticationException.class)
  ...
  public ErrorMessage resourceNotFoundException(AuthenticationException exception) {
    ...
  }
}
```

See more at: https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring
Deep in dive Spring MVC Handling Exception:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-rest-exceptions

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot for solution. In this situation, I think I do not need to use `Spring Security` s exception in the `AuthenticationEntryPoint` class, right?